# Cannot EnterText on local device using Xamarin UItest Cross Platform

Tags: xamarin, calabash, uitest

So I am playing with Xamarin UI Test (which uses calabash under the hood, I think) and cannot enter text on my locally attached device

I have a Cordova/Ionic app (6.3.1/1.2.4) visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin/update 3. I've added the apk to the project

I want to write the test using a local device and then upload it to test cloud for automated testing.

I have a simple input text field called testInput

```
<ion-view view-title="Where are the Coffee shops?">
    <ion-content>
    <input type="text" id="testInput" class="testInput" placeholder="Enter some text here" />
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

To enter text in there I find it via the id, and EnterText

```
        app.EnterText(c => c.Css("input#testInput"), "blah blah blah");
```

This works fine in the test cloud (screen shots prove this). But if I run this on my locally attached device (samsung S6 edge Android 6.0.1) I cannot get it to enter any text.

I have tried using different key boards, swift key, google, samsung default.
On each I have turned off predictive text. no joy

I have tried scrolling down to the item, then EnterText (with selector)

```
    app.ScrollDownTo(c => c.Css("input#testInput"));
    app.EnterText(c => c.Css("input#testInput"), "blah blah blah");
```

Taping the item then enter text (no selector)

```
        app.Tap(c => c.Css("input#testInput"));
        app.EnterText("blah blah blah");
```

Each time I get the same thing. The input box gets selected. The keyboard appears and then no text gets entered. The log says
Using element matching Css("input#testInput").

```
Tapping coordinates [ 384, 1456 ].
Entering text 'blah blah blah'.
Took screenshot. { Path: "XXXX\CoffeeShop.UITest\bin\Debug\screenshot-1.png", Title: "EnterSomeText2" }
```

In case it matters I have initised the app as follows

```
        var retval =  ConfigureApp
            .Android
            .EnableLocalScreenshots()
            .ApkFile(@"D:\XXXXX\bin\Android\Debug\android-debug.apk")
            .StartApp();
        return retval;
```

Does anyone know anything else to try???

Comment: Hi Amjid! Just as a sanity check, when you run in Test Cloud, are you running on the same exact device make / model? Also, which version of UITest are you using? You could give the pre-release a try, we do make frequent updates.

Comment: hi @ChristopherFuentes I was not using samsung S6 edge. I changed it to use S6 edge(android 5.1.1) and S7 edge (android 6.0.1)
It failed on the S6 but worked on the S7. So it looks like its phone related.
I also updated to the latest dev build but that didnt solve it

Comment: @AmjidQureshi Have you tried removing the `input` from the CSS selector name?  For example:   `app.EnterText(c => c.Css("#testInput"), "blah blah blah");`  In older version of UITest, I've seen issues when having the element type in the selector.   Sample: https://github.com/mattregul/XamarinTestCloud_WebviewSamples/blob/master/Code/UITests/Tests.cs#L186

Comment: If that doesn't help, could you please provide your project or sample so we can take a deeper look?